# Magento 1 Set Template Doesnt work

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, template

I'm new to M1.
I'm trying to add a new custom option type in product

My Config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <CompanyName_ModuleName>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </CompanyName_ModuleName>
</modules>   
<global>
    <blocks>
        <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
                <catalog_product_edit_tab_options_option>CompanyName_ModuleName_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Options_Option</catalog_product_edit_tab_options_option>
            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>
        <modulename>
            <class>CompanyName_ModuleName_Block</class>
        </modulename>
    </blocks>
    <catalog>
        <product>
            <options>
                <custom>
                    <groups>
                        <modulename translate="label" module="modulename">
                            <label>Special Types</label>
                            <render>CompanyName_ModuleName_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Options_Type_Stone</render>
                            <types>
                                <stone translate="label" module="modulename">
                                    <label>Stone</label>
                                </stone>
                            </types>
                        </modulename>
                    </groups>
                </custom>
            </options>
        </product>
    </catalog>
    <models>
        <catalog>
            <rewrite>
                <product_option>CompanyName_ModuleName_Model_Catalog_Product_Option</product_option>
            </rewrite>
        </catalog>
    </models>
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="product.info.options">
            <action method="addOptionRenderer">
                <type>stone</type>
                <block>modulename/catalog_product_view_options_type_stone</block>
                <template>companyname/modulename/catalog/product/view/options/type/stone.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</global> 
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <CompanyName_ModuleName_Router>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>CompanyName_ModuleName</module>
                <frontName>modulename</frontName>
            </args>
        </CompanyName_ModuleName_Router>
    </routers>
</frontend>

<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <companyname_modulename after="Mage_Adminhtml">CompanyName_ModuleName_Adminhtml</companyname_modulename>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
</config>
```

My Block

```
class CompanyName_ModuleName_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Options_Type_Stone extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Options_Type_Abstract
{
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setTemplate('companyname/modulename/catalog/product/edit/options/type/stone.phtml');
    //var_dump($this->hasData('template'));exit;
    $this->setCanEditPrice(true);
    $this->setCanReadPrice(true);
}
}
```

In my phtml file I `var_dump` something to test but it doesn't work. `var_dump` in the block works. And i put my phtml in

> design/adminhtml/default/default/template/companyname/modulename/catalog/product/edit/options/type/stone.phtml

Did I do somthing wrong? Any help would be very appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can call phtml file by using below code

1) call phtml via block file

```
class CompanyName_ModuleName_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Options_Type_Stone extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Options_Type_Abstract
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setTemplate('modulename/catalog/product/edit/options/type/stone.phtml');
    }
}
```

your template file should be in

> design/adminhtml/default/default/template/modulename/catalog/product/edit/options/type/stone.phtml

Comment: I tried, but it still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: make sure Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Options_Type_Abstract class should override properly into local file, or try just testing purpose into core file